# HAProxy change domain based on request path

Tags: reverse, haproxy

I have a structure where all calls made to :

http://www.example.com/c/CUSTOMERID/rest/of/path

are redirected to

http://CUSTOMERID.example.com/rest/of/path

I currently am doing this with nginx reverse proxy but would like to make it work with HAProxy.

CUSTOMERID can be anything, there's no way for me to know in advance what it will be.

Is there a way to do this with HAProxy?

Thank you

Comment: Offtopic. Server configuration is not a programming issue.

Comment: @MarcB you may be right, but with its if/unless, regexes, string/numeric/boolean logical operators, variables... the configuration of HAProxy for things like URL rewriting seems almost as much like "programming" to me as, say, writing a stored procedure in MySQL, which is also a "server" but still closer to "programming" than "configuration."  Off topic? I don't know... it seems fuzzy to me.